# Can I get SQL injection attack from SELECT statement?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, vb.net, sql-injection

**2 Questions actually:**

I know i must use Stored Procedures as much as Possible, but i would like to know the following please.

**A:** Can i get a SQL Injection attack from a SELECT statement such as (Select * from MyTable) ?

**B:**
Also, can i get a SQL Injection attack when I use the SQLDataSource in ASP.NET?

Comment: using stored procedures "as much as possible" isn't going to make a huge difference, since most of the time when people take this approach they're just concatenating strings in the stored procedures.  The important thing is to use parameterized queries, be they in stored procedures or not.  Don't kill yourself trying to make everything a stored procedure when perhaps it shouldn't be one :)

Comment: I suggest to enjoy this [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/327/) comic, a good lesson about sql injection

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To answer your questions.

**A:** Yes, you can get an SQL Injection attack from any query **that takes parameters** (even calling stored procedures if you are not using the provided methods by your platform and doing it via SQL calls).

I was asked to provide an example of how an injection can be made even by using stored procedure. I've seen applications developed that do use stored procedures, but in this way:

```
// C# - DON'T DO THIS!
String regionName = assignedSomewhereElse();
SQLCommand sqlCmd = DatabaseConnection.CreateCommand();
SQLCommand sqlCmd.CommandText =
    String.Format("EXECUTE sp_InsertNewRegion '{0}'", regionName);

sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Obviously, this is not the way to call a stored procedure. You should use your platform's abstractions or parametrized queries.

---

**B:** `SQLDataSource` is an abstraction layer for your database. It will create the SQL queries for you and automatically sanitize them in order to prevent injection.

In order to avoid injection, either:

- Sanitize your inputs
- Use the abstraction layer provided by your platform.
- Use parametrized queries.

Comment: Can you give an example of how someone would do an injection attack on a stored procedure?  Thanks.

Comment: @Steve: An example has been provided.

Comment: Is it possible to get a SQL injection attack from ANY query? eg `SELECT * FROM MyTable`. Where does the injection occur in this instance? No concatenation of strings or external variables are being introduced.

Comment: @El Ronnoco: Since no other variables are concatenated to the query, it wouldn't be possible to do a SQL injection attack on that query.

Answer (score 6):

You can get an SQL injection attack anytime that you are not using parameterized queries, for the most part.

If your example,

```
 SELECT * from MyTable
```

there isn't any user-inputted data, so that should be fine.  However, something like:

```
 SELECT * from MyTable WHERE name='x'
```

(`x` being a parameter) then there's a chance that someone injects some SQL into their name.

B: ASP.NET uses parameterized queries because it builds the query based on the parameters that you provide programmatically.

Comment: More precisely, you can get SQL injection anytime you interpolate untrusted content into a query string and execute it as dynamic SQL.  You can't use query parameters for table names, column names, SQL keywords, expressions, etc. so even if you use parameters you can still create unsafe queries.

Answer (score 3):

Injection hacks occur when you give the user the ability to manipulate the query, and with the parametrized queries most (if not all) threats are neutralized as special characters are escaped to make only the query you intended executable

Example:
Search Box: [            ] [ GO ]

```
select * from myTable where keywords like '%$searchTerm%'
```

Then the hacker inserts a '; to terminate the query and can write any other query they want.

Answer (score 2):

if you are not using parameterized queries but are concatenating you can get sql injection for any kind of SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE or INSERT statement

Answer (score 2):

In response to your comment - 'what must i do?'

For starters you can validate the text boxes or whatever control will be used to allow input. If you're looking for a number make sure that they only put in numbers, if they are inputing a word make sure no punctuation is available. Take out characters like -- and ' unless it is absolutely needed. You can do all of this with ajax and/or javascript. Also,[Here is an interesting Article on protection from injection.](http://www.programminghelp.com/web-development/asp-net/how-to-protect-against-sql-injection-attacks-in-asp-net/) Also [parameterized queries are a great option](http://aspnet101.com/aspnet101/tutorials.aspx?id=1)

Comment: N, you can't do this through javascript. If you rely on javascript to remove potentially dangerous chars, an attacker can simply forge an http post request with all the " ' " he needs. This validation must happen server side.

Also "discard all " '  " unless absolutelly need is something I also consder bogus. " ' " Are valdi characters in normal, human language, and must be preserved. The sanitation has to properly escape then - and one's programing language or framework should provide a way to do that properly.

Answer (score 1):

SQL injection requires the SQL string to be combined with some user-controlled parameters, so if the Select statement is constant, it is immune to injections.  On the other hand, if you're adding a "WHERE user_id =" + userIdString, then injection is possible.

Avoiding injections doesn't require stored procedures, and you shouldn't count on sanitizing your inputs.  Instead, just bind to the parameters instead of manipulating strings.

Take a look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Any time you allow a user to give input data into a dynamic sql query you are at risk of injection. And a sqldatasource does not protect  you from injection. Inserts,deletes, drops,etc will still occur.

Comment: Then what must i do? Since SQLDataSource does use Parameter.