# What are dangers from running SELECT queries supplied by users?

Tags: sql

If I limit my user's input SQL statement so that it starts with SELECT, can any injection attacks be run in that case? Am I leaving a different security hole (beyond getting access to all data that the schema has permission to access)?

**Edit**
What if I also ban semi-colon(;) ?

Comment: Do you have a problem with pre-compiled, parameterized queries?  That basically removes any possibility of SQL injection.

Comment: This is vulnerable to probably the most well-known SQL injection attack. https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I get SQL injection attack from SELECT statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099391/can-i-get-sql-injection-attack-from-select-statement)

Comment: Technically it's not an injection if you allow an entire query...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, yes. A SQL injection attack given a simple select:

```
var sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Field = '" & fieldValue & "';";
```

Could be modified by replacing the value of the variable `fieldValue` with the following:

```
fieldValue = "'; DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE 0 = 0 OR '' <> '";
```

Which when the script is run will result in two statements being created and executed:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Field = ''; DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE 0 = 0 OR '' <> '';
```

This is just a simple example, any number of statements could be run that would insert, update, delete, etc...

To expand upon your edit about stripping semicolons, yes by changing the `fieldValue` variable to something like:

```
fieldValue = "' OR 1 = 1 OR '' <> '";
```

You would end up with the following:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Field = '' OR 1 = 1 OR '' <> '';
```

Which, if that were a user table could run the risk of allowing elevated privileges or logging in as an incorrect user.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  If you are allowing your users to input SQL into a website (which is the typical case when you are talking about SQL injection attacks) you are opening yourself up to an avenue of attack.  It doesn't matter if you restrict individual characters, or limit it to only beginning with a SELECT statement, in the end SQL has simply too many ways to parse input (and the web has even more) to catch every possible malicious query without also blocking most possible non-malicious ones.

Always parse your input.  Ideally, use a framework or at least a set of stored procedures (which do NOT dynamically build and execute a query within them) for database access.

Tell us a little more about the problem you are trying to solve, and we can help more.

EDIT (post-comment): If you are trying to create an internal tool for your support staff, you'll want to create a tool with basic searching capabilities.  Give the user drop downs to select what fields they want to search against, and pass the input into a stored procedure or a framework to minimize your risk.  If you assume your support staff can write SQL, just give them a login to your database - it's easier to restrict access to 'SELECT' statements for a user in a database access tool like Management Studio than to secure a website.

Comment: It's only for a small internal support tool. I want the support team to be able to select anything from the database, but not affect the data. I don't have control over the database itself (so can't write stored procedures, etc.)

Comment: If your support team knows SQL, why not just give them SQL Server Management Studio, with user accounts limited to 'Select' statements?  If they don't know SQL, why not just make a search function that passes data into Entity Framework or stored procedures?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sql injection attacks can start with select:

```
SELECT * FROM USERS; DROP TABLE USERS
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, injection attack's can still happen typically by an attacker using the 'Where' clause on a Select Statement. i.e. They may be able to obtain full details using this.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing the SQL and figuring out the access is still risky. For example, what if someone passes the following?

```
"select * from table_1; drop table X;"
```

You could use stored procedures and bind inputs as some of the users suggested.

Also make sure the database user that you are using to connect your app/client in your case has only "SELECT" permissions. I believe this is more effective than making sure all SQLs are selects only. (which is tricky to implement, by the way).